# how can i add a variable attribute to this design

Tags: database, database-design

According to my design I have car models(BMW, toyota, ...) and car types(coupe, sedan, van, ...). So my CAR table has those two tables primary key and price information.

My problem is that I have one more car type named "customizable". that car type dont have an exact price because its open for bargain. I mean a coupe BMW's price is always same like sedan BMW but customizable BMW varies.

Current design doesnt meet that need. How can I solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to store the negotiated price against the Allocation - since that's the table that has the Car and Customer in it.

Or you could add another table which gets queries when the Type is 'custom'.